# Drive boots but isn't "located"

Tags: disk-utility, filesystem, apfs, driver, ntfs

The APFS drive I'm writing this text from cannot be located by macOS High Sierra. Everything that needs it misses whatever link is necessary to get to it. I can boot, I can use it, I cannot "find" it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finder shows it mounted and works fine with it.

[image]

What exactly is this error? How do I fix this?

`diskutil list` (it's /dev/disk1, and I've connected another drive since the images above)

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.9 TB     disk0s2
   3:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         100.0 GB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.9 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume                         1.6 TB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume                         20.2 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume                         515.1 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume                         8.6 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data Media                   4.0 TB     disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Media-1                 6.0 TB     disk3s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data Media-2                 2.0 TB     disk3s3
```

`mount`

```
/dev/disk1s1 on / (apfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s4 on /private/var/vm (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

[image]

Comment: I think might be one of the first people to create this bizarre bug. The two things I was doing were erasing **other** external disks with Disk Utility, and uninstalling and reinstalling Paragon NTFS a couple of times. Disk Utility didn't touch this drive, so maybe Paragon NTFS messed with the way drives are read? It's notoriously hard to uninstall sometimes. I think I removed everything about it, but I'm not sure now how to reset things back to normal.

Comment: If this needs another dozen comments to clarify, please vote to close it as needing details or clarification. An answer to start narrowing fixes is more welcome than Q&A in the comments...

Comment: I have had weird problems like this after using ParagonNTFS, many years ago. If possible, I recommend switching to Tuxera, as I did. Its write performance is worse than Paragon—noticeably so, in real world use—but I'll take the hit for a stability advantage, and I've found Tuxera to be very solid since I moved.

Comment: I switched to Tuxera too and it works great. As a recommendation to anyone reading, look into filesystems with native support if possible. Tuxera did screw up a NTFS Windows partition once for me - not by mounting it, but after I edited files on it from macOS. I mount it every day since, but since I don't touch the files from macOS, no issues there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Just as it came, it went. There is Paragon NTFS/Disk Utility background to this issue mentioned in a comment above, that might come into play here.

What little I did was figure out there were still Paragon NTFS files in the computer. This is well documented online, the command below should point you to the locations.

```
sudo rm -rf "/Library/Application Support/Paragon Software/"
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.paragon-software.installer.plist
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.paragon-software.ntfs.loader.plist
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.paragon-software.ntfsd.plist
sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.paragon-software.ntfs.notification-agent.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/Filesystems/ufsd_NTFS.fs/
sudo rm -rf /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.paragon-software.installer
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/ufsd_NTFS.kext/
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/ParagonNTFS.prefPane
```

I then left the computer running overnight copying files with Finder as an emergency preccaution to at least save the files.

Today, I restarted the computer (which I had already done once before without results), and after it took longer than usual to boot, everything was working again.

Guess you can add it to the long history of people having trouble using NTFS on macOS. Tuxera, Paragon, something always comes up sooner or later.

---

Alternatively, things I was gonna try today. I read someone saying that you can fix the Partition Table by booting to an external macOS drive and adding a new partition to the drive with problems, which "overwrites the partition map" back to normal. I also thought about booting into Safe Mode and seeing if it was recognized there, and physically reconnecting the SATA port of the drive.